# Can I simplify $\cos \frac{1234 \pi}{5}$ and $\sin \frac{1234 \pi}{5}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have

$$\cos \frac{1234 \pi}{5} + i \cdot \sin \frac{1234 \pi}{5}$$

I believe I can simplify the $1234$ further, but how?

Comment: $1234=246\cdot 5 + 4$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\frac{1234\pi}5 = 246\pi + \frac{4\pi}5$

Answer (score 2):

To complement mrf, we can say that $cos(\frac{1234 \pi}{5})=cos(\frac{4 \pi}{5}$).  Because there are the periodic identities which stays that:

$\sin( \theta+ 2 \pi n)= \sin \theta $

$\cos( \theta+ 2 \pi n)= \cos \theta \qquad n \in \mathbb{Z}$

This happens because the period of sine and cosine funtions is $2 \pi$.

Comment: You can _not_ say that $\frac{1234\pi}{5} = \frac{4\pi}{5}$; you can just say that their sines (and cosines) are equal.

Comment: Rather than saying these fractions are equal, one should say that they are congruent mod $2\pi$.

Comment: Steven Stadnicki you are right.I forgot to fit in the question.Its done